# Linux device driver maps serial fpga registers to memory

Tags: serialization, linux-device-driver, fpga, memory-mapping

There is a FPGA based register set (512 bytes) that can be read/write with a special protocol. I want to write a device driver that makes it possible for the user process to read/write these registers like a memory (array, pointer) and not with read() / write() functions or by dealing with the protocol.

1. Is this really possible?
2. Where I can find some description how to do this?
3. What are the main steps?

Comment: Your plan probably has flaws.  First you state that the registers have a *"special protocol"*.  But then you want the user process to *"read/write these registers like a memory"*, but without *"dealing with the protocol"*.  That sounds contradictory to me.

Comment: the driver can/should deal with the protocol, not the user process

Comment: Yes, the purpose of a device driver is to handle such a protocol.  But if you map the registers for userspace access, then there is no mechanism for the driver to intervene,  That's what the **read()** and **write()** syscalls provide.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it should be possible.
2. Start with [LDD3](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/), chapter 3 and chapter 15. Those chapters will give the basics of how to make your driver to expose the register set to the user space.
3. Basically, your task can be broken into two parts: access to the register set from your driver and make those registers accessible from user space. The first part depends on your "special protocol" and as you did not provide any information about it, you are on your own here. The second part is to add char device to the system and implement `mmap()` call in the driver which will allow you to access a memory region as a buffer. This is well described in the LDD3.

Comment: @0andriy, do you mean that the register set should not be exposed to the user space at all?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying.

Comment: OK, does your suggestion means:

Comment: 1) OK Mikhail, does your suggestion means:
there is a local copy of the register set in memory space of the driver and the user space have access to it (with mmap)?

But how the driver can track changes (if the user space write some data)?

2) What is wrong as an idea? I want to have transparent access with little overhead, because it is an embedded system.

Answer (score 0):

You need a device driver that implements mmap() so that the user space application can access the registers by load and store instructions.

Your driver should disable caching when it maps the registers so that reads and writes always interact with your FPGA. Possibly your driver also needs to disable buffering, in case your hardware cannot handle burst writes to the registers.

My designs generally are structured this way. I have a generic device driver enables applications to mmap() the control logic. The device driver also enables the application to use poll() to wait for interrupts from the hardware, in case that is needed. It is so much less headache not to have to update a device driver just because the hardware has changed.